# DirectPipelineRunner - does it support standard glob patterns?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

Executing our pipeline in the cloud runs fine. But when running it as a `DirectPipelineRunner` (i.e. locally) it borks, and complains about the file pattern supplied. The file pattern uses a glob.

Is this intended behaviour when running locally?

```
[..]
TextIO.Read.from("gs://cdf-testing/NetworkClicks_123456_2015010[1-2]*")
[..]

Feb 18, 2015 4:19:09 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner run
INFO: Executing pipeline using the DirectPipelineRunner.
Feb 18, 2015 4:19:10 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.GcsUtil expand
INFO: matching files in bucket cdf-testing, prefix NetworkClicks_123456_2015010[1-2] against pattern NetworkClicks_123456_2015010[1-2][^/]*
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to read from source: com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.TextReader@55dbc59b
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReaderUtils.readElemsFromReader(ReaderUtils.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO.evaluateReadHelper(TextIO.java:702)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO.access$000(TextIO.java:98)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO$Read$Bound$1.evaluate(TextIO.java:310)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.TextIO$Read$Bound$1.evaluate(TextIO.java:306)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.visitTransform(DirectPipelineRunner.java:611)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:200)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformTreeNode.visit(TransformTreeNode.java:196)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:109)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:204)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner$Evaluator.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:584)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:328)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DirectPipelineRunner.run(DirectPipelineRunner.java:70)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:145)
    at com.shinetech.tpc.engine.CDFEngine.loadClicks(CDFEngine.java:88)
    at com.shinetech.tpc.engine.CDFEngine.doMagic(CDFEngine.java:75)
    at com.shinetech.tpc.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No match for file pattern 'gs://cdf-testing/NetworkClicks_123456_2015010[1-2]*'
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.FileBasedReader.iterator(FileBasedReader.java:101)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.ReaderUtils.readElemsFromReader(ReaderUtils.java:35)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, the two runners should behave the same. Sounds like that's a bug in the DirectRunner. Thanks for the report -- will reply here when the fix is out.

Comment: Just to follow up, this fix has been on Github since Feb 23rd and will be in the next release to maven mid-month.